# .htaccess - redirect favicon

Tags: apache, .htaccess, favicon

How do I redirect all requests for favicon.ico in root directory or any subdirectory to /images/favicon.ico

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Try this rule:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^favicon\.ico$ /images/favicon.ico [L]
```

---

**Edit**    And for *favicon.ico* with arbitrary path segment depth:

```
RewriteCond $0 !=images/favicon.ico
RewriteRule ^([^/]+/)*favicon\.ico$ /images/favicon.ico [L]
```

Comment: This works for /favicon.ico but not for /folder/favicon.ico
Some browsers are requesting favicon.ico in local folder even though it's specified as /images/favicon.ico so I wanted to redirect the currently failing requests to the correct location

Comment: Expanding this concept, a more detailed rewrite rule also accounting for non-favicon icons: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37107216/4378314

Answer (score 8):

For a favicon at `www.mysite.com/images/favicon.ico`
the most robust method would be:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/images/favicon\.ico$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (.+)
RewriteRule ^(.*)favicon\.(ico|gif|png|jpe?g)$ http://%1/images/favicon.ico [R=301,L,NC]
```

Explanation:

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/images/favicon\.ico [NC]` :
- ensures that the redirect rule does NOT apply if the correct URI is requested (eg a 301 redirect will write the correct favicon URI to browser cache - and this line avoids processing the rule if the browser requests the correct URI)
- [NC] means it's not case sensitive

`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (.+)` :
- retrieves the http host name - to avoid hard coding the hostname into the `RewriteRule`
- this means you can copy your .htaccess file between local/test server and production server without problems (or the need to re-hardcode your new site base url into your RewriteRule)

`RewriteRule ^(.*)favicon\.(ico|gif|png|jpe?g)$ http://%1/images/favicon.ico [R=301, L]` :
- `^` is the start of the regex
- `(.*)` is a wildcard group - which means that there can be zero or any number of characters before the word `favicon` in the URI (ie this is the part that allows root directory or any subdirectories to be included in the URI match)
- `\.(ico|gif|png|jpe?g)` checks that the URI extension matches any of `.ico`, `.gif`, `.png`, `.jpg`, `.jpeg`
- `$` is the end of the regex
- `http://%1/images/favicon.ico` is the redirect url - and it injects the hostname we retrieved in the previous `RewriteCond`.  Note that the `%1` is a called a [RewriteCond backreference](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) this means it is the last `RewriteCond` that has been met. (eg `%2` would be the 2nd-last `RewriteCond` that to have been met)
- `R=301` means it's a permanent redirect - which stores the redirect in the browser cache. Be careful when testing - you'll need to delete browser cache between code changes or the redirect won't update.  Probably leave this out until you know the rule works.
- `L` means its the last redirect to be followed in this `.htaccess` file - you won't need this to get the rule working since line 1 won't be met once the browser is directed to the correct url.  Without the either line 1 or `L` the RewriteRule will result in a permanent loop (since the redirect URL will keep satisfying the `RewriteRule` conditions).  However, it's a good idea to add the `L` anyway if you have other rules following the favicon rules - since on a favicon.ico request, you can (probably) ignore any following rules.

You can test `.htaccess` rules at http://htaccess.mwl.be/

Final Note:
- be careful that you don't have any other RewriteRule in an `.htaccess` file located in any of your sub-directories.
- eg if you put *this* answer in your `www.mysite.com/` root folder `.htaccess` file, a `RewriteRule (.*) xxx` type rule in your `www.mysite.com/images/` folder can mess with the results.

Answer (score 4):

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^(.*)favicon\.ico /images/favicon.ico [L]
```

Comment: the ^ in front is very important

Comment: This is giving me an internal server error.
Is it beacause (.*)favicon.ico also matches /images/favicon.ico so it becomes a loop

Comment: Checked error log and it states "Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error" so looks like it is indeed redirecting to itself. How do I get around that?

Comment: Right I skipped [L] flag. Try as per Gumbo's reply.

Comment: I think I need to use this with a RewriteCond to say if request URI not /images/favicon.ico not sure the correct syntax though

Answer (score 0):

This quick rewrite should do the trick:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)favicon.ico /images/favicon.ico
```

Answer (score 0):

I know the question is tagged `.htaccess`but, why not use a symlink?

```
ln -s images/favicon.ico favicon.ico
```

Comment: Because then I would have to create a symlink in every single directory & subdirectory on the site

Comment: If the server is looking for favicon.ico at the root and you can't have it there, one symbolic link would do...I'm going to implement this now (to not be tied to Apache) but if it needs doing on a per-directory basis then perhaps it's time to re-consider the configuration...