# sql inserting twice

Tags: php, sql

Hello i have a sql statement that ranks my records and inserts the ranks into a database.

The problem i am having is that when i run the script. It deletes the old rankings. And inserts the new rankings fine, but it inserts every ranking twice. So there will be 2 rank 1's, 2 rank 2's, ect ect.

The kicker to my problem, is if i delete all the records in phpmyadmin. Then run the script. It doesnt make duplicates.

I tried just letting the script delete, to debug if the delete script is working, and it deleted all the rows fine. Hence im really confused :(

if you could look at my code and give me some insight that'd be awesome. Thank you

```
<?php

// Connect to the database we want to insert/update
$Server_Location = "localhost";
$Server_User_Name = "x";
$Server_Password = "y";
$Database_Name = "z";

// Create connection
$Conn_Info = mysqli_connect($Server_Location, $Server_User_Name, $Server_Password, $Database_Name);

// Check connection
if ($Conn_Info->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $Conn_Info->connect_error);
} 

if($_GET['Password'] != 'q'){
    die();
}


$Sql_Delete_Duplicate = "DELETE FROM ranks";

if ($Conn_Info->query($Sql_Delete_Duplicate) === TRUE) {
    echo "User Deleted";
} 
else {
    echo "Error User Not Deleted";
    echo $Conn_Info->error;
}




// Overall Games - Rankings (1000)
$Top_1000_Sql = "Select games, overall_games_user.ID as UserID, Name FROM overall_games, overall_games_user WHERE overall_games.User_ID = overall_games_user.ID AND DATE(Date_Updated) = DATE(NOW()) GROUP BY User_ID ORDER BY Games DESC LIMIT 10000";

$Top_1000_Results = $Conn_Info->query($Top_1000_Sql);

$rank = 0;

if ($Top_1000_Results->num_rows > 0) {
    echo $Top_1000_Results->num_rows;
    while($Top_Player = $Top_1000_Results->fetch_assoc()) {

        $rank += 1;
        $User_ID = $Top_Player["UserID"];
        $Games_Played = $Top_Player["games"];

        $Insert_Top_Player_Sql = "INSERT INTO ranks (Rank_Type,Rank, User_ID, games)
                            VALUES ('Total', {$rank}, {$User_ID}, {$Games_Played})";


        if ($Conn_Info->query($Insert_Top_Player_Sql) === TRUE) {
            echo $rank . "-";
        } 
        else {
            echo "Error User Not Added";
            echo $Conn_Info->error;
        }

    }
}

// Yesterday Games - Rankings






// Graph Stats

/*
SELECT AVG(Games) FROM overall_games WHERE DATE(Date_Updated) = DATE(NOW()) AND User_ID IN (SELECT ID FROM overall_games_user WHERE division LIKE('%BRONZE%'));
SELECT AVG(Games) FROM overall_games WHERE DATE(Date_Updated) = DATE(NOW()) AND User_ID IN (SELECT ID FROM overall_games_user WHERE division LIKE('%SILVER%'));
SELECT AVG(Games) FROM overall_games WHERE DATE(Date_Updated) = DATE(NOW()) AND User_ID IN (SELECT ID FROM overall_games_user WHERE division LIKE('%GOLD%'));
SELECT AVG(Games) FROM overall_games WHERE DATE(Date_Updated) = DATE(NOW()) AND User_ID IN (SELECT ID FROM overall_games_user WHERE division LIKE('%PLATINUM%'));
SELECT AVG(Games) FROM overall_games WHERE DATE(Date_Updated) = DATE(NOW()) AND User_ID IN (SELECT ID FROM overall_games_user WHERE division LIKE('%DIAMOND%'));

*/

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using Group By without aggregate function so change your query to:

`$Top_1000_Sql = "Select Count(games) as gameCount, overall_games_user.ID as UserID, Name FROM overall_games, overall_games_user WHERE overall_games.User_ID = overall_games_user.ID AND DATE(Date_Updated) = DATE(NOW()) GROUP BY UserID ORDER BY Games DESC LIMIT 10000";`

Also note change in **GROUP BY UserID** in above SQL

In $Games_Played variable fetch value of count:

`$Games_Played = $Top_Player["gameCount"];`

Comment: I further notice you are using another column `Name` you are not using it anywhere you can remove that too:

`$Top_1000_Sql = "Select Count(games) as gameCount, overall_games_user.ID as UserID FROM overall_games, overall_games_user WHERE overall_games.User_ID = overall_games_user.ID AND DATE(Date_Updated) = DATE(NOW()) GROUP BY UserID ORDER BY Games DESC LIMIT 10000";`

Comment: grouping by UserID instead of User_ID fixed my problem. Out of wanting to understand, may i ask why this fixed my problem? because before i was grouping by User_ID. Is it because when im grouping by User_ID i have multiple rows of the same User_ID in overall_games and only one .ID in overall_games_user? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

1. Try Changing VALUES to VALUE in your query.
2. Also it sometimes so happens that you have an .htaccess to point every thing to the index file. Naturally the browser will request the script twice, once for the script it self, the other is for the favicon.

The fix is to Try to edit the .htaccess to prevent redirection to the index file when the browser is requesting for favicon.ico

Try these two things. I hope it would solve your problem :) Else let me know again.

Comment: thanks for the help, i tried the other solution just in that i dont really know how to fix the .htaccess requesting

Comment: open .htaccess in an editor. the file can be found in the root folder of your site. Check this out then :- 
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2408110/htaccess-redirect-favicon)