two sess_xxx files created for each start_session()
I am upgrading from centos7 to AlmaLinux to run my php8 code, but during some basic tests I am finding that session_start() is creating two sess_xxxxxxxx files when run on my AlmaLinux 8 environment, whereas it only creates one when run on my classic centos7. Why would that be?
To add to the confusion, I am finding the following code is showing just one sess_ file, but if you visit the folder behind the scenes and check the files then you see the additional/second file too (as if the file is created later somewhere).
run script:
<?php

echo "<LI><b>session-start</b><PRE>BEFORE: " . print_r(glob(ini_get('session.save_path') . "/*"), true) . "</PRE>";
session_start();
echo "<LI><b>session-started</b>=<PRE>AFTER: " . print_r(glob(ini_get('session.save_path') . "/*"), true) . "</PRE>";

stdout:
session-start
BEFORE: Array
(
)
session-started=
AFTER: Array
(
    [0] => /var/www/vhosts/xxxxxxx/private/php_sess/sess_2qbs9shppmphjf7igarhmj0k42
)
2qbs9shppmphjf7igarhmj0k42

linux ls:
[18:19:28 php_sess] $ pwd
/var/www/vhosts/xxxxxxx/private/php_sess

[18:19:30 php_sess] $ ls
sess_2qbs9shppmphjf7igarhmj0k42  sess_eup7lqe2f7otoavfj75v5u7693


You might want to check other questions like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62293540/why-are-multiple-php-sessions-being-created

Thanks Progman, but not seeing any solutions in there - did you have a specific comment in mind?

The one about the favicon.ico request, which would run before your actual request and might start a new session before hand. Please [edit] your question to include all the PHP configuration/settings related to sessions. Also add the access_log of the webserver you are using to see all the requests coming in before your PHP script is running, while your PHP script is running and after your PHP script is running.

ok - yes - with help from Progman (and Why are multiple PHP sessions being created?), it does seem that there is a double-tap causing two sess_ files. This double-tap seems to be coming from said unexpected request for favicon.ico and my .htaccess directive FallbackResource /index.php which seems to then drive that request back into the index.php which then starts a new session (and creates the second sess_ file).
Removing that FallbackResource directive resolves the problem (although I'll have to work out what the consequences of that will be)
